# Are the multiplications of i.i.d random variables , i.i.d?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

If we know that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d random variables, and $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are also i.i.d random variables, can we say $X_1Z_1$  and $X_2Z_2$ are i.i.d random variables too? suppose that $X_1$ ,$X_2$, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are all independent random variables.

Comment: For this edited version (I mean assuming that all the random variables are independent), yes they are.

Answer (score 4):

Pick $X_1$, $X_2$ iid, and $Z_2 = X_1$, $Z_1 = X_2$, then $Z_1$, $Z_2$ are also iid. On the other hand $X_1Z_1 = X_1X_2$ and $X_2Z_2 = X_1X_2$ are not iid.

Comment: Yes you are right. I edited the question.

Comment: Which should not prevent you from accepting this answer.